# Upload images with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to upload photos using Django as backend.

The model that I use is:

```
def inspection_picture_path(self, filename):
    return 'inspection_{0}/{1}'.format(self.inspection.id, filename)


class InspectionPictures(models.Model):
    inspection = models.ForeignKey(Inspection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to=inspection_picture_path, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Inspection-{}".format(self.inspection.id)
```

In `settings.py` I have :

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'master/static/master/img/inspection_pictures'),
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'master/static/master/img/inspection_pictures'),)
```

The function in the `view` where I'm trying to save the images is as follows:

```
def save_pictures(inspection, pictures):

    print(pictures)

    for picture in pictures['pictures']:
        n_picture = InspectionPictures()
        n_picture.inspection_id = inspection.id
        n_picture.picture = picture
        n_picture.save()
```

`print(pictures)` gives me following result:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'pictures': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: samsung-s8.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Simulator Screen Shot 6 Jul 2017, 15.43.55.png (image/png)>]}>
```

Thus, the images are there but when I try to save them I get an error:

**AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

My view where I call the `save_pictures` function is as follows:

```
@token_required
@transaction.atomic
def add_inspection(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.POST.get('data'))
        pictures = request.FILES

        n_inspection = Inspection()
        n_inspection.user_id = data['user']['id']
        n_inspection.data = json.dumps(data)
        n_inspection.save()

        save_pictures(n_inspection, pictures)

        return HttpResponse("Its ok.", status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong.", status=400)
```

And `Inspection` model is :

```
class Inspection(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    data = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, default=None)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Inspections"
```

Comment: Could you show us the view?

Comment: can you please post model Inspection code as well?

Comment: @be_good_do_good I've updated my question.

Comment: @FazilZaid Updated.